# Exact same hashing in PHP as in linux/bash with mkpasswd and salt? (SHA-256) (solved)

Tags: php, bash, sha256

I can hash in PHP with a salt and SHA-256:

```
echo crypt('testpassword','$5$rounds=5000$testsalt$');
```

With this, the stored hash is:

```
=5rf7xsfKjXFA
```

But if I try to do the same in linux/bash, I get a different result:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-256 -S testsalt testpassword
```

With this, the hash is:

```
$5$testsalt$8NbtxBXDUq60UB.kmvqYOHepmEdmXS39tViByKR.UU2
```

Can anyone help with this? - Solved, see comment.

I used

```
php --version
PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u12 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2021 17:51:39) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0+deb9u12, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

and

```
mkpasswd 5.2.17
Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Marco d'Itri
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: With `crypt('testpassword','$5$testsalt$')` I get `$5$testsalt$8NbtxBXDUq60UB.kmvqYOHepmEdmXS39tViByKR.UU2` (php 5.4)

Comment: Thanks Fravadona, the issue was not to escape the "@" while using the php cli.